# Gridview Get Value Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

Dynamically create textbox in gridview this way:

```
int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
int tot = e.Row.Cells.Count;
for (int i = 1; i < tot; i++)
{
    TextBox txtValor = new TextBox();

    txtValor.Width = 15;
    txtValor.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;
    txtValor.ID = "txt"+index.ToString()+i.ToString();
    txtValor.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); 
    txtValor.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[produ].ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtValor);              
}
```

I can not get the value, already tried these ways:

```
quant = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
quant = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls[0])).Text;
quant = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("txt"+i.ToString()+j.ToString())).Text;
quant = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text; // this way i get the value of the cell and not the textbox
```

Tgis is the code-behind ASPX: the textbox was create by row databound.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="XX-Small" ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="35" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#6E7265" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#BDC0C4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" Wrap="True" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" /
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show your ASPX gridView markup? Also during which method are you creating the new TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

C# has a method that lets you find a control by ID:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs MyEventArgs)
{
      // Find control on page.
      Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBox2");
      if(myControl1!=null)
      {
         // Get control's parent.
         Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
         Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
      }
      else
      {
         Response.Write("Control not found");
      }
}
```

Once you have the control, cast it to a textbox control and then just get the text property:

```
string txtValue = ((TextBox)myControl1).Text;
```

EDIT: Dimitri E makes a good point in that you should find a way to assign unique IDs to your controls for this method to work reliably

Link for reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
txtValor.ID = "txt";
```

change this to:

```
txtValor.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
```

Then you will be able to find it later with your code, otherwise you are creating a bunch of textboxes with the same id: "txt"

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    TextBox txt =  (TextBox)FindControl("txt" + i.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(txt == null ? "Not Found!" : txt.Text);
}
```

this code will iterate through textboxes called txt0, txt1, txt2, will try to find them and will display a messagebox with a message. If textbox found then value will be displayed, ootherwise "Not Found!" will show. You can replace messagebox with something different or just output it to a label.

```
protected void Page_Load(...
{
    // 1. Get data from DB if Session variable is null or data have changed
    // 2. Save it to Session Variable
    // 3. Create Controls using a session variable (this one will 
    //       be called on each post-back)
    // 4. Click event is called after Page_load completes. 
    //       Your textboxes are in place to be found.
    //      
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good point, though it does not show him how to actually find the control

Comment: another thing to consider: you must recreate controls on each postback prior to attempting to read values out of them. Otherwise you will get a null in this line: TextBox txt =  (TextBox)FindControl("txt" + i.ToString());

Comment: yeah, but something is loading data to GridView1, right?